# Using wildcards in VBA for Conditional Formatting (Excel 2003)

Tags: vba, excel, wildcard, conditional-formatting

I worked up the following VBA to add a bunch of conditional formatting to a worksheet in Excel 2003 (which only allows 3 conditions otherwise), but it won't function correctly with wildcards. If I substitute the wildcards for exact values, it runs correctly. I suspect the last statement about <> may require adjusting, but I don't know how to jive the LIKE "Wildcard" with <> at the end. VBA code below:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range)
    Set MyPlage = Range(“C3:I11,C13:I34”)
        For Each Cell in MyPlage

    If Cell.Value Like “A*” Then
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 38
    End If
    If Cell.Value Like “B*” Then
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    End If
    If Cell.Value Like “C*” Then
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 34
    End If
    If Cell.Value Like “D*” Then
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 40
    End If
    If Cell.Value <> “A*” And Cell.Value <> “B*” And Cell.Value <> “C*” And Cell.Value <> “D*” Then
    Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need wildcards since it's just a basic If...ElseIf...End If structure:

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range)
    Set MyPlage = Range(“C3:I11,C13:I34”)
        For Each Cell in MyPlage

    If Cell.Value Like “A*” Then
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 38
    ElseIf Cell.Value Like “B*” Then
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    ElseIf Cell.Value Like “C*” Then
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 34
    ElseIf Cell.Value Like “D*” Then
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 40
    Else
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Rory, this worked well! To mix it up a little, what if I want to format an entire row rather than just the relative cell in the row? I can do this in later Excels but can't figure it out using VBA in Excel 2003.

Comment: There shouldn't be any version difference: ` Cell.Entirerow.Interior.ColorIndex = 40`